# Karma testing with typescript and angular 2 is throwing Typeerror for "System.config"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular

I'm super new to testing, I'm using angular 2 as a new beginning to learning.

**ERRROR:**

```
INFO [Chrome 42.0.2311 (Mac OS X 10.9.3)]: Connected on socket xo5ufjmFKLGc5QSuAAAB with id 34336816
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js
ERROR [karma]: Uncaught TypeError: System.config is not a function
at http://localhost:9876/base/js/angular.js?4c894ae47e8d04bb01965dbf22fa08aed20f0eb2:25575

ERROR [karma]: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at http://localhost:9876/base/app/app.js?8a00e7f6717b2dd7118e800d05625a443a4b2065:13
```

### **QUESTION:**

How can I get remedy the TypeError and uncaught Reference Error, so my main.spec.js can pass?

---

**Karma.conf**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon May 18 2015 18:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
     'app/app.js',
     'tests/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**tests/main.spec.js:**

```
import Foo from '../app/app.js';

describe('ES6 Foo', function () {

  let foo;

  beforeEach(()=>{
      foo = new Foo();
  });

    it('should call foo.thing and test default value', function(){
        expect(foo.thing).toEqual(0);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./js/traceur.js"></script>
        <script src="./jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/angular2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main-app></main-app>
        <script>
            System.import('app/app');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2"/>
import {bootstrap, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
    selector:'main-app',
    injectables: [

    ]
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'app/main.html',
})

class MainApp {
    thing;
    constructor(){
        this.thing = 0
    }

    add(){
        this.thing++;
    }
    subtract(){
        this.thing--;
    }
}

bootstrap(MainApp);
```

Comment: Why are you giving .js files to karma.conf and not .ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is directly linked to this bug

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2049

The problem is that the module loader is being loaded from the wrong URL (hence the 404 error you are seeing) and that makes System not be available.

The Angular2 team uses Protractor with Webdriver. You should be able to get Chrome to work in that configuration.